# Is there a way to install symfony3 complete with a composer.json?

Tags: symfony, composer-php

all my Code is splitted into bundles, which i require with the composer.json.
Now i want to install the whole project with `composer install`, but when i try it out, the symfony folders doesn't appear and i get the following error message:

```
 [RuntimeException]                                                                                     
 Could not scan for classes inside "app/AppKernel.php" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder
```

Is there a way to request the symfony installation files ?

This is my `composer.json`:

```
{
"name": "mygloriousname",
"license": "proprietary",
"type": "project",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/AppKernel.php",
        "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.1.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ]
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
    "symfony-var-dir": "var",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [create-project](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project).

This is how you can install [Symfony via composer](https://symfony.com/doc/master/setup.html#creating-symfony-applications-with-composer)

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name
```

This command does the following steps:

1. takes the project for [symfony/framework-standard-edition](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/framework-standard-edition) from packagist
2. downloads the repository: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard
3. runs `composer install` in that newly downloaded project

edit: Obviously for your use case you have to replace `symfony/framework-standard-edition` with your project identifier and either put it on packagist, your own composer repository (e.g. with [Toran Proxy](https://toranproxy.com/)) or [register the repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository) in your global composer config.

You can probably find a few more examples usually as part of some kind of skeleton application.

**While this is doable it's not the preferred way for deploying an application for a good reason.** You can't just update a project like this only replace the existing one, which will cause downtime or require some symlink-juggling and even then has some drawbacks. Also you still have to run all the initial setup steps, like specifying the database connection info, each time. You could work around this (or manually type in all these parameters), but having a real deployment tool for example using ansible will be a much better choice for a scenario like this.

Comment: The create-project command is not the one i have searched for, because i can't install in a non-empty directory. So composer can't read my composer.json.

Ansible is a bit overpowered for my project :)


So i must check in the whole symfony structure (excluded the `.gitignore` files into git.
 
The configuration files i had copied with gulp after installation is completed.

But thanks for your detailed answer.

Comment: That is the issue I tried to explain in the last paragraph: composer is _just_ for installing dependencies, not for deploying your project. What I described is a limited way of setting up a project, but that is already bending composer's purpose a bit. Updating an existing project - like you want to do - requires a lot of mangling in composer, because it requires task it is not set out for. In simple cases you can instead just do a `git pull` if the project is managed by git. The more common scenario is using a deployment tool: http://www.phptherightway.com/#deployment-tools.

Comment: The reason this is more complicated than you imagine is that there are sometimes tasks involved beyond downloading the new files when updating a project. For example you might have to restart other services, clear caches (not just the composer cache, but for example in the database or in redis/memcached), maybe invalidating sessions. Those are just the ones right out of my head. There are plenty more. Most of them require deeper knowledge of the application and are very project specific, they usually have to run in the right order. This is is not in composer's scope. That is why it's so hard.

Comment: Long story short: You are using the wrong tool for the job.